# Как из XML массива вытаскивать файлы

Tags: php, xml

Например есть такой XML интернет магазина как мне вытащить в php всю продукцию у которой `categoryId` = 3, ну и вообще как правильно обратиться к элементу

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-08-08 15:31
        )

    [shop] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => Site
            [company] => Site
            [url] => http://site.com/
            [currencies] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [currency] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => RUR
                                    [rate] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [categories] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [category] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Обувь
                            [1] => Одежда
                            [2] => Аксессуары
                            [3] => Мужская
                            [4] => Женская
                            [5] => Мужская
                            [6] => Женская
                            [7] => Club
                        )

                )

            [offers] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [offer] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 30920
                                            [type] => vendor.model
                                            [available] => false
                                        )

                                    [name] => Футбольная форма Adidas Germany 2016
                                    [url] => http://site.com//catalogue/odezhda/muzhskaya/futbolnaya_forma_adidas_germany_2016_7499.html
                                    [price] => 1185
                                    [oldprice] => 1690
                                    [currencyId] => RUR
                                    [categoryId] => 6
                                    [market_category] => Одежда, обувь и аксессуары/Мужская одежда/Одежда
                                    [picture] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => http://site/goodsimg/00000007082/~1ge2.jpg
                                            [1] => http://site.com/goodsimg/00000007082/2ge2-1.jpg
                                        )

                                    [delivery] => true
                                    [vendor] => Adidas
                                    [vendorCode] => 7499
                                    [model] => Футбольная форма
                                    [description] => Домашний комплект футбольной формы Сборной Германии ЕВРО 2016Преданность команде. Тотальный комфорт.Футболка и шорты сделаны из лёгкого влагоотталкивающего материала, который обеспечивает максимальный комфорт. Синтетический материал нового поколения, который не впитывает влагу, а пропускает ее через свою структуру и выводит на поверхность, заставляя мгновенно испаряться.Характеристики:Влагоотталкивающая ткань обеспечивает мягкое хлопковое ощущение, прохладу и комфортКомандная эмблема вшита нитью премиум-качестваМатериал: 100% полиэстер высшего качестваПригодна для машинной стиркиТонкая дышащая ткань на спине
                                    [param] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 46
                                            [1] => Мужской
                                            [2] => Взрослый
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 30921
                                            [type] => vendor.model
                                            [available] => false
                                        )

                                    [name] => Футбольная форма Adidas Germany 2016
                                    [url] => http://site.com//catalogue/odezhda/muzhskaya/futbolnaya_forma_adidas_germany_2016_7499.html
                                    [price] => 1185
                                    [oldprice] => 1690
                                    [currencyId] => RUR
                                    [categoryId] => 6
                                    [market_category] => Одежда, обувь и аксессуары/Мужская одежда/Одежда
                                    [picture] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => http://site.com/goodsimg/00000007082/~1ge2.jpg
                                            [1] => http://site.com/goodsimg/00000007082/2ge2-1.jpg
                                        )

                                    [delivery] => true
                                    [vendor] => Adidas
                                    [vendorCode] => 7499
                                    [model] => Футбольная форма
                                    [description] => Домашний комплект футбольной формы Сборной Германии ЕВРО 2016Преданность команде. Тотальный комфорт.Футболка и шорты сделаны из лёгкого влагоотталкивающего материала, который обеспечивает максимальный комфорт. Синтетический материал нового поколения, который не впитывает влагу, а пропускает ее через свою структуру и выводит на поверхность, заставляя мгновенно испаряться.Характеристики:Влагоотталкивающая ткань обеспечивает мягкое хлопковое ощущение, прохладу и комфортКомандная эмблема вшита нитью премиум-качестваМатериал: 100% полиэстер высшего качестваПригодна для машинной стиркиТонкая дышащая ткань на спине
                                    [param] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 48
                                            [1] => Мужской
                                            [2] => Взрослый
                                        )

                                )
```

Comment: Можете добавить часть нерасплетенного xml?

Answer (score 1):

через `xpath` метод:

```
$xml->xpath('//offer[@categoryId="3"]')
```